# Printing a multiplication table with nested loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a really hard time trying to figure out this exercise.

Print the 2-dimensional list mult_table by row and column. Hint: Use nested loops. Sample output for the given program:

```
1 | 2 | 3
2 | 4 | 6
3 | 6 | 9
```

This is the code that I have so far

```
mult_table = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [3, 6, 9]
]

for row in mult_table:
    for num in row:
        print(num,' | ',end='|')
    print()
```

What I get is this

```
1 ||2 ||3 ||
2 ||4 ||6 ||
3 ||6 ||9 ||
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong!  I have also tried to do end=' ' but that still leaves a space and | at the end of each row.  Please help.  I am using Python 3 btw.

Comment: You are really close! You already can print the values, and now you just need to print the separators, which isn't that hard. Come on, you got this! Hint: `print` has more to it than one may think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Low-Level:** Your code shows two `'|'` after each number because that's what you're telling it to do (one of them is passed to `print()` right after `num`, and one of them is added by the use of `end='|'`, which tells `print()` to add a `'|'` at the end of the printed string).

Using `end=''` avoids the second `'|'`, but you still end up with a pipe character at the end of each row from the `print()` call.

To get `'|'` between items, but not at the end of the row, you need to handle the last item in each row specially (or, better use `" | ".join(row)` to add the separators automatically).

**High-Level:** You're likely not solving this problem the way it was intended to be solved.

Your answer hard-codes the multiplication table, but you could be generating it as part of the loop, like:

```
# Store the size of the table here 
# So it's easy to change later
maximum = 3
# Make a row for each y value in [1, maximum]
for y in range(1, maximum + 1):
    # Print all x * y except the last one, with a separator afterwards and no newline
    for x in range(1, maximum):
        print(x * y, end=' | ')
    # Print the last product, without a separator, and with a newline
    print(y * maximum)
```

This solves the specific problem given, but we can now change the value of "maximum" to also generate a square multiplication table of any size, and we don't have to worry about errors in our multiplication table.

Answer (score 3):

Use join with map:

```
mult_table = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [3, 6, 9]
]

for row in mult_table:
    print(" | ".join(map(str, row)))
```

Output:

```
1 | 2 | 3
2 | 4 | 6
3 | 6 | 9
```

Answer (score 2):

You're overthinking this. One loop should be enough here. You can unpack the inner lists and specify a `sep` parameter.

```
for m in mult_table:
     print(*m, sep=' | ')

1 | 2 | 3
2 | 4 | 6
3 | 6 | 9
```

---

If you want two loops, you will need to programmatically control the separators and the end characters to be printed out at each inner loop iteration.

```
for i in mult_table:
    for c, j in enumerate(i):
        sep = '|' if c < len(i) - 1 else ''
        end = ' ' if c < len(i) - 1 else '\n' 
        print(j, sep, end=end)

1 | 2 | 3 
2 | 4 | 6 
3 | 6 | 9
```

Comment: I actually think he should use the nested loop because that's the point of his exercise. To understand nested loops even if there are other ways to do it.

Comment: @GeorgeBou should it matter that this is a homework exercise?

Comment: No it doesn't to us. But maybe it does to him. That's why he put it on the title

Comment: @GeorgeBou sure, but just because it's what OP wants doesn't necessarily mean it's what they need.

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer.  Yes the object of this exercise is to understand nested loops so the first answer is something I don't understand yet but the second answer was very helpful.  The enumerate function is still very new to me but I will play around with it.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
for row in mult_table:
    line = 0
    for num in row:
        if line < len(mult_table) - 1:
            print(num, '| ', end = '')
            line += 1
        else:
            print(num)
```

This will iterate through each of the rows step by step checking through the `if` statement to see if it has reached the end of the row, printing the `|` between each `num` in the `row` until the end which will simply print the `num` followed by a return to next line.

Placing the `line = 0` inside the first loop is essential as putting it outside the first loop will cause `line` to already meet the `else` requirement of the `if` statement. With it inside the initial loop, each iteration causes `line` to reset to `0`, which allows the nested `if` to function properly.

Answer (score 0):

```py
   row_length = len(mult_table[0]) #Gets length of the first row.

   for row_index, row in enumerate(mult_table): #Loops trough each row.
       count = 1 #Sets count
       cell_index = 0 #Sets cell index count
       while count != row_length: #Checks if end of the row
           print(f'{mult_table[row_index][cell_index]} | ', end='') #Print
           count += 1 #Count increase
           cell_index += 1 #Count increase
       else:
           print(f'{mult_table[row_index][cell_index]}') #Print
           count += 1 #Count increase
           cell_index += 1 #Count increase
```

Here is a solution using nested loops and without using .join.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
mult_table = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [3, 6, 9]
]
row_num = 0


for row in mult_table:
    i = 0
    for cell in row:
       
        if i < len(mult_table) -1:
            print(cell,'| ', end='')
            i +=1
        else: print(cell)
'''
```

Comment: Hi :), It seems like this answer has already been answered. If you have nothing extra to add to it, please consider removing this post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I came up with. I haven't learned some of the things I see in the examples above, so I just made what I have learned work. My first post, I'm sure if it is ever seen I will learn etiquette and format etc... One problem I feel like exists, is the rowlen variable. I want it to be the amount of elements in the row, not the amount of nested list elements in the mult_table list.

```
# existing code
mult_table = [
[1, 2, 3],
[2, 4, 6],
[3, 6, 9]
]

# my code
#   |
#  \|/
#   V

x = '| '
rowlen = len(mult_table) - 1

# print(x, rowlen) # testing values

for row in mult_table:
    for cell in row[0:rowlen]:
        print(cell, '{}'.format(x), end='')
    print(row[rowlen])
```